# Sum in Nested JSON from MySQL in Vue JS Component

Tags: mysql, json, vuejs2

This is the content from MySQL 8 in JSON.

The MySQL field "ticket_json" is JSON type

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "ticket_json": [{
        "id": 1570801381559,
        "qty": 2,
        "name": "Cognac",
        "price": 1000
    }, {
        "id": 1570801382391,
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Jäger Bomb",
        "price": 900
    }, {
        "id": 1570801386549,
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "VodK Ananas",
        "price": 900
    }],
    "created_at": "2019-10-11 15:43:08",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-11 15:43:08"
    }, {
    "id": 2,
    "ticket_json": [{
        "id": 1570830556370,
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Peace & Love",
        "price": 600
    }, {
        "id": 1570830560279,
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Tonic",
        "price": 600
    }],
    "created_at": "2019-10-11 23:49:22",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-11 23:49:22"
    }
}]
```

I retrieve data stored like the method:

```
getTickets() {
    fetch('/api/path)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
        this.tickets = data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

I display data like this:

```
<div v-for="ticket in tickets">
    {{ totalTicket }}
</div>
```

The "computed" code:

```
    computed: {
    totalTicket() {
        var itemsTotal = 0;
        for(var key in this.tickets) {
            var item = this.tickets[key];

            var subitems = item.ticket_json;
            var subItemsTotal = 0;
            for(var key in subitems) {
                var subitem = subitems[key];
                var subItemsTotal = subItemsTotal + ((subitem.la_qtt * subitem.le_tarif)/100);
            };
            var itemsTotal =+ subItemsTotal;
            console.log(itemsTotal);
            return itemsTotal;
        };
    }
},
```

In the loop, i would display the sum (totalTicket) of each object (qty * price)

**Problem, It display the same first result in all loop**

I am not very familiar with Javascript. If you can help me, thank you

Comment: Can you post a data example on https://www.db-fiddle.com , As MySQL 8 supports [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) for easy JSON to records parsing and on which you can run SUM on..

Comment: Like that ?
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7KP39WyeJzPTPAq9waiuhC/1

Comment: Move the `return itemsTotal;` outside the for

Comment: Thanks Max, but when I do that, it's the result of the last loop that's always displayed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `totalTicket` you loop through **ALL** elements of the array and you calculate the total of **ALL** elements.

You have also defined twice the `var key` (the two for loops) and you have defined the `subItemsTotal` ouside the 2nd loop and inside the loop, you have also defined `itemsTotal` ouside the first loop and inside the 2nd loop.

You must create a **method** that take a **single** value and calculate the total.

### Html

```
<div v-for="ticket in tickets" :key="ticket.id">
  For Ticket id {{ticket.id}} the Total is {{ totalSingle(ticket) }}</div>
</div>
```

### Code

```
methods: {
    totalSingle(ticket) {
      var itemsTotal = 0;
      var subitems = ticket.ticket_json;
      var subItemsTotal = 0;
      for (var key in subitems) {
        var subitem = subitems[key];
        subItemsTotal = subItemsTotal + (subitem.qty * subitem.price) / 100;
      }
      itemsTotal += subItemsTotal;
      return itemsTotal;
    }
}
```